# Printer redirection without RDS role on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, printing

I have a Windows 2012 AWS VM configured for Administrative Mode only. However, sometimes I would like to print from the server to a redirected RDS printer.

But client printers never show up on the server, which does not have the RDS role installed. Yes the client "Local resources\Printers" option is ticked. There are no events in Event Viewer on the server for TermServDevices. The Local Group Policy node "Remote Desktop Services" does not even exist for Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates.

Is this just a configuration exercise, or is it not possible at all?
If it is not possible using stock Windows, can ThinPrint or alternative be used on this setup (RDP admin mode) to get it to work?

Comment: Check the eventlog to be sure the printer driver is found, without the RDS role your server will miss the rdp easy print's driver, which will make it harder to your printer to show. The easiest way, share one printer from your computer and double click on it from the remote server, it will install the corresponding driver, after you erase that shared printer and test again to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The RDS Easy Print driver won't be installed on the server if the RDS Role isn't installed, so you'll need to install the appropriate printer driver(s) on the server in order for the printer(s) to be redirected.

Comment: I installed generic Canon PCL6 drivers, but the server is not doing any redirection. On some servers (2008) I can see attempts to load printers in Event Log (TermServDriver or TerminalServices-Printer) but no such events on the 2012 R2 server.

Comment: You can't install just any driver, you have to install the matching driver. If the client is using a specific driver then the server has to use the same driver. If the driver (and the driver name) does not match then the printer will not be redirected.

Comment: I think you missed my comment and part in the original question where it states there isn't even an Event Log entry for trying to match the driver or any attempt at redirection. I'm inclined to think it's some setup/permission/role/feature/configuration issue. Solve that, and then we may see a driver issue.

Comment: I found the the Easy Print driver is installed without the Role, it shows up in Print Management All Drivers, but mapping doesn't take place. Adding the role fixed an issue on one server we had.